# Saving changed PDF with form fields from embedded chrome viewer and uploading to server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf

We are using the default embedded chrome pdf viewer to display a pdf with form fields. User can easily fill out the form. When done we have to click the download button that allows them to download the form with or without changes.
[image]

What we would like to achieve is to have a save button in this component that would fetch the pdf with changes and upload it to the server.

We don't mind adding a library for it, currently finding it hard to find documentation and accessing anything in this embedded pdf viewer.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do, is to add a Submit button, which does submit the data (or the form as document, under some circumstances) back to your server. In the latter case, you then could push back the filled form; in the former, you could use an utility to fill the blank form with the data and push that result.

This works as long as the form is not too intelligent (although Chromium has a relatively good PDF viewing component, which understands a bit of Acrobat JavaScript). Otherwise, you better recommend to download the blank form and have it filled out in a good PDF viewer (industry standard for macOS and Windows is Adobe Acrobat Reader). If you need to gather data in this situation, the submit function would be your choice.